# Install adt Package

Tags: installation, pycharm, adt

Through pycharm I can't install the adt package. I also tried through the terminal which at the command:

```
pip install adt
```

responds with this error message:

> ERROR: unable to find a version that meets the adt requirement (from
> versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for adt

Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Which [adt](https://pypi.org/search/?q=adt&o=) package do you intend to install? Are you sure the name of the package is just `adt` and nothing else?

Comment: Yes i am sure that the name of the package is only "adt" and the version is 0.0.1

Comment: Well if you're sure would you mind giving a reference to where the package is and why you want to install it? Because I haven't found any repository for it.

Comment: I think it's [this one](https://github.com/benzid-wael/adt) and apparently the build is failing so it might not be working. I checked the [source code](https://github.com/benzid-wael/adt) and the entire project is just an empty template, it doesn't have any functionality or working code.

Comment: You're welcome, no problem.